# Outlook Addin - Wait for a response

Tags: events, event-handling, outlook, http-post, add-in

I have an Outlook Addin that creates a contact on a webpage by making an API call to that webpage. When the Addin runs (via the click of a button), the API call is made and the user is taken to that webpage to fill in the contact information. After the user has filled in the information and clicks on submit, I would like to catch that event in Outlook and get the user back to Outlook to carry out further actions. Any possible ways of getting this done? I've been looking online but haven't found any solution as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to display the web page in a modal dialog in your own form. When the form is closed, you can take whatever action is necessary.

Comment: That's a good idea actually. I'm going to give that a go. Any possible links to your solution?

Comment: No, that was just off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: When the user clicks on that submit button, I should obviously try to close that modal dialog and then carry on with Outlook. Any possible suggestions on how I can get that done?

Comment: When you host a browser control, you can expose your own COM object to the script through the window.external property. Your script can then call any function you chose to expose.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class helpful. It is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

Also you may consider repurposing ribbon controls. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.